# How use Postgre's HSTORE type in Flask application?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a beginner in Flask & I tried to make one of my table column as HSTORE in my model. But I got an error.

Can anyone point to me how I can use HSTORE type in flask app.

I have checked too many links and can't find anything helpful for me.

In SQLAlchemy manual, they documented that PostgreSQL HSTORE type as well as hstore literals are supported.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#hstore-type

In my model, I have added the below code.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

#.........
class Submission(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    form_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('form.id'))
    origin = db.Column(db.String())
    form_data = db.Column(db.Hstore()) # I have also tried HSTORE(), hstore() 
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

But when I try to run my flask app, I got the below error.

```
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Hstore'
```

I'm using the latest version of Flask - 1.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLAlchemy HSTORE type as well as hstore literals are supported, But you have to manually import the hstore extension using

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import HSTORE
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict
```

Afterwards you should describe the column name and column type with hstore

```
form_data = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE))
```

Python Dictionaries should be stored inside the columns using `MutableDict` in Flask (sqlalchemy)

So your code need to be changed as

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import HSTORE
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableDict

#.........
class Submission(db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 form_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('form.id'))
 origin = db.Column(db.String())
 form_data = db.Column(MutableDict.as_mutable(HSTORE))
 timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Also remember to create `Hstore` extension for your database as follows

login in psql postgres from command prompt

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Assuming you have created the required database under postgres role,
lets say `db_test` is the database

Connect to `db_test`

```
postgres=# \c db_test
```

Now you should be connected to `db_test`
Create hstore extension

```
db_test=# CREATE EXTENSION hstore;
```

hstore extension should be successfully created,
List out the extensions installed on your database using

```
db_test=# \dx
```

Hope this will solve your problem